# {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\Exception(code: 0): One or more input exceptions have occurred

Tags: magento2, error, validation, exception

I'm getting the following issue since today, i'm not able to find out what is going on. It was all working fine for the past few months, and no files was modified recently. What could be the problem? ( Unfortunately, the support from the extension provider is expired, i'm trying to resolve the problem myself.)

checked:  cron jobs are running fine.

checked:  ticket.php was not modified.

checked:  mysql is running

error from exception log

```
[2020-09-14 14:15:09] main.CRITICAL: One or more input exceptions have occurred. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\Exception(code: 0): One or more input exceptions have occurred. at /home/-----/public_html/app/code/Aheadworks/Helpdesk/Model/Ticket.php:246)"} []
```

this is the partial from ticket.php, starting from line 230

```
/**
 * Add cc_recepients validation to regular validation
 *
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
 */
public function validateBeforeSave()
{
    try {
        parent::validateBeforeSave();
    } catch (ValidatorException $catchedException) {
    }

    if (!empty($catchedException)) {
        $validateException = $catchedException;
    } else {
        $validateException = new ValidatorException();
    }

    $this->fillFromAdminData();
    $emailRule = new \Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
    $ccRecipients = $this->getCcRecipients() ? $this->getCcRecipients() : [];
    $emailsToValidate = array_merge([$this->getCustomerEmail()], $ccRecipients);

    foreach ($emailsToValidate as $email) {
        if (!$emailRule->isValid($email)) {
            foreach ($emailRule->getMessages() as $message) {
                $validateException->addMessage(new Error($message));
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($validateException->getMessages())) {
        throw $validateException;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As spoken try

```
if (isset($catchedException) && !empty($catchedException)) { 
    $validateException = $catchedException;
} else {
    $validateException = new ValidatorException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If php7.1 can you try this in your code?

```
try 
{
    parent::validateBeforeSave();
} 
catch (ValidatorException|Exception $catchedException) 
{

}
```

Comment: yes, it is php 7.1.33, updated to that, but the problem still presist. The line 246 of the erro message was referring to '$validateException = new ValidatorException();' can you show me  how i can comment this validation function out?

Comment: it works if i take out the if-else statement, and changed to '$validateException = new ValidatorException();' only, otherwise it is giving the error  [2020-09-16 21:45:09] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: catchedException . Any idea?

Comment: late reply sorry but you can try

if (isset($catchedException) && !empty($catchedException)) {
}

Comment: thanks Nadeem, that works too. Please update your answer I will accept it.